# Detect Greatest Dynamic Range Changes In Audio Sample

Tags: algorithm, audio

Forgive/correct any wrong terminology in the below (I hope it makes sense!):

I want to detect the biggest dynamic audio changes in a given sample, (ie. the moments when the sound wave 'grows'/'accelerates' the most).

For example, if the audio goes quiet at some points during the sample, I want to know when the music comes back in after, and order these data points by the relative dynamic range (volume?) increase (largest to smallest).

My audio sample is a buffer of `float32[]` and sample rate, and I would like a resulting array of objects each containing:

- start frame index
- start time (seconds ... `frameIndex/sampleRate`?)
- end  frame index
- end time (seconds)
- dynamic change value

My naive approach iterates linearly and detects points at which the value starts rising until it is no longer rising, and then calculates the rise over run for each sub interval between those points.. but this is not producing the correct result.

Any ideas or existing algorithms that do this?

Not picky on languages, but anything with syntax like C#, Java, JavaScript preferred!

Comment: My prototype uses the 0th channel data of an [AudioBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBuffer) instance atm

Comment: Perhaps you could calculate the derivative at every point, and then select points or regions of time where the rate of change is above a threshold? You could then calculate the average slope over each of those regions and order them in terms of which got louder the fastest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a little unsure as to how much audio DSP background you have so apologies if treading over old territory.

Essentially this is a problem of trying to find the envelope of the signal at any given point. 
Since the audio signal will be fluctuating between -1 and 1, the value of any individual sample will not yield much 
information about the loudness or dynamic range.

What would be best to find is the [root mean square](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/definitions/instantaneous-average-and-rms-values-4) of the signal over some frame of audio data

Written in pseudo code, and assuming you already have your audio Data, a function and way of grabbing the rms data could be:

```
   function rms(frame[], frameSize)
   {
       var rmsValue = 0;

       for(int i = 0; i < frameSize; i++)
       {
           rmsValue += frame[i] * frame[i]; // square the sample and sum over frame
       }

       rmsValue = sqrt(rmsValue / frameSize);

       return rmsValue;
   }




// Main

   var frameNum = floor(numberOfAudioSample / frameSize) // for analysis just floor to a whole number of frames, if thi is real-time, you will need to deal with a partial frame at the end

   var frame = []   // an array or buffer to temporarily store audio data
   var rmsData = [] // an array or buffer to store RMS data  

   for (var i = 0; i < frameNum; i++)
   {
       for (var j = 0; j < frameSize; j++)
       {
           sampleIndex = j + (i * frameSize)
           frame[j] = audioData[sampleIndex]
       }
       rmsData[i] = rms(frame, frameSize)
   }
```

You can then compare elements of the RMS Data to find when the dynamics are changing and by how much.
For digital audio RMS will be constrained to between 0 and 1. To get dBFS then all you need to do is `20 * log10(rmsData)`

Finding the exact sample where dynamic range changes will be tricky. The frame index should be accurate enough with a small enough size of frame.
The smaller the frame, however, the more erratic the RMS values will be. Finding a time in seconds is simply `sampleIndex / samplingRate`

With a small frame size you may also want to low pass filter the rms data. It depends on whether this is for a real-time application or for non real-time analysis.

To make things easy, I would prototype something in [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) or MATLAB first

Comment: Wow amazing pointers especially given my knowledge in the area is almost zero! Will give this a go and post results. I’m thinking about a frame size of sampleRate/1000 to get ms.. but will see if that’s too erratic. Thanks again

Comment: Audio frame sizes will typically be in powers of 2. A frame size of 1024 samples, about 23ms at 44100kHz sampling rate is fairly standard size for analysis.

Comment: Will use that then, that should be easier! Thanks

Comment: This is my [waveform](https://ibb.co/mPimV8) for the audio data. I implemented your idea, and whilst it correctly identifies a new maximum:

`The value at 18.668843537414965 seconds is 0.21922676122012053. dBFS -13.182128644188689`

That value is surpassed at around 23, 39 and 46 seconds in the sample.. which is perplexing.  I had this same issues with cruder approaches like the mean, and min/max of each frame.

Comment: Not to worry, that may not be as unusual as you might think.  What may be worthwhile doing is plotting the rms data alongside the waveform. There may be some DC offset throwing things off, or the loudness at those points you mentioned may be genuinely greater.

Comment: Follow up: If I base it on the max diff between rms' (ie. `rmsData[i] - rmsData[i-1]`) then that produces the correct result for the given sample.. I wonder if that is a rational approach

Comment: Thats rational, if you take the difference between two consecutive elements in rmsData and divide by length in time of a frame, `frameSize / samplingRate`, you are working out the rate of change of rms.